# Understanding the 're.search()' behavior in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Here is the python code i have used to split up letters and digits from a string of alphanumerics:

```
input_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
import re
print re.search('[a-z]*', input_string).group()
print re.search('[0-9]*', input_string).group()
```

In output i am getting the string of letters but not getting the string of digits. If i modify the code like following the output is showing the digits:

```
print re.search('[0-9]*$', input_string).group()
```

I am used to `grep` and i found it's functionalities are similar to those of `re` module, if i run the following command in shell i get the desired result:

```
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" | grep "[0-9]*"
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: you need to use `re.findall` function, since `re.search` would return only the first match.

Comment: Why arent you using raw strings instead in your pattern? like `r'[a-z]*'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you to use `re.findall` function (*in-order to do a global match*) instead of `re.search` because `re.search` would return only the first match.

```
>>> input_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
>>> print re.findall(r'\d+|[a-z]+', input_string)
['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '1234567890']
```

And also don't use `[a-z]*`, it would return empty strings also. `*` would repeat the previous token zero or more times where `+` would repeat the previous token one or more times.

```
>>> print re.search(r'\d+', input_string).group()
1234567890
>>> print re.search(r'[a-z]+', input_string).group()
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**Why the first one works where the second fails?**

```
>>> print re.search('[a-z]*', input_string).group()
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>>> print re.search('[0-9]*', input_string).group()

>>>
```

`*` repeats the previous token zero or more times ie, it would match an empty string which exists before each non-matching characters. First `[a-z]*` returns `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` because this substring was located at the start. If the input is like `8abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, it would return an empty string. This behaviour is because of `re.search` function, where it stops after finding the first match. Here `8` is not matched by the above regex, so as i said, `[a-z]*` regex would match the empty string which exists just before to the `8`.

regex = `[0-9]*`, string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

`re.search` stops after finding the first match. Here `a` is not matched by `[0-9]` but `[0-9]*` matches the empty string which exists before `a` because `*` would repeat the previous token **zero** or more times. That's why you got an empty string as output in the second case.

```
>>> print re.search('[0-9]*$', input_string).group()
1234567890
```

Since we added an end of the line anchor, it would search for zero or more digits at the line end. It would return an empty string as match if it finds no more digits at the last.

```
>>> print re.search('[0-9]*$', '12foo').group()

>>>
```

Comment: There's only one match in his input string, why does he need `findall`?

Comment: he need to use re.findall only for the first case. But he needs to change `*` to `+` for both cases.

Comment: You should explain more clearly that it's matching the empty sequence of digits at the beginning of `input_string`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't think he needs `re.findall`. With `+` and `re.search` he gets expected results.

Comment: @user5061 if he want to get the output both alphabets and numbers using a single regex then he need to use `re.findall` function.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Is this behavior of `*` (that will match an empty string before the chatacter if pattern is not matched) python `re` specific because using `GNU grep` in `bash` i am getting my desired output as i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: yep, `re` module is designed like that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The main problem in his code was the `*` and `+`. Anyway, good edit.

Answer (score 1):

> In output i am getting the string of letters but not getting the
>   string of digits.

I just checked both ruby and perl, as well, and they produce the same results.

The `digit pattern` matches:

1. The zero-width spot that is between the first character and the second character.
2. The zero-width spot that is between the second character and the third character.
3. etc.
4. The sequence of numbers at the end of the string.

However, re.search() only returns the first match.

The lower case `letter pattern` matches:

1. The sequence of letters at the beginning of the string.
2. The zero-width spot between the 1 and 2.
3. The zero-width spot between the 2 and 3.
4. etc.

> if i run the following command in shell i get the desired result:
>
> ```
> echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" | grep "[0-9]*"
> ```

In a bash shell, I get:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" | grep "[0-9]*"
abcdefghijk
```

And I get similar strange results with echo, grep, and other patterns.

**Response to comment:**

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ echo "abc123" | grep -o "[a-z]*"
abc
$ echo "abc123" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
$ echo "abc123" | grep -o "[0-9]*$"
123
$
```

Comment: Use the `-o` switch of `grep` i.e. `echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" | grep -o "[0-9]*"` . It will only print the matched text, not the whole line. BTW i have `GNU grep`.

Comment: @heemayl, I get the same result as python, ruby, and perl: `echo "abc123" | grep -o "[a-z]*"` produces `abc`, and `echo "abc123" | grep -o "[0-9]*"` produces no output, and `echo "abc123" | grep -o "[0-9]*$"` produces `123`